# AJAX request for many links

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm new to jQuery AJAX. I want to build bookmarking system something like Twitter do *(favorites)*. I have a lot of links. So it's not useful to write AJAX request for each link. That's why I want use just one request script for all links.

Let's say I have the links something link this:

```
<a href="#" id="1"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i></a>
<a href="#" id="2"><i class="icon-star"></i></a>
<a href="#" id="3"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i></a>
```

So I want to write AJAX request that do something like this when user clicks to one of those URLs.

```
if (class="icon-star-empty"){
    ajaxURL = "/insertBoomark"
} else{
    //it means class=icon-start
    ajaxURL = "/deleteBookmark"
}

$.ajax({
  url: ajaxURL,
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : linkID}, // I don't know how to get linkID too :(
  success: if class was icon-star empty then change it to icon-star-empty else change it to icon-star
});
```

I know that is not correct syntax.
How can I solve this problem? Please help :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to store user's bookmarking at server side? You can store user's preferences at client side, in cookies.

Comment: I need it for another reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("i").on("click", function() {

    if ( $(this).hasClass("icon-star-empty") ){
        ajaxURL = "/insertBoomark"
    } else{
        //it means class=icon-start
        ajaxURL = "/deleteBookmark"
    }

    var linkID = $(this).parent().prop("id");
    var obj    = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: {id : linkID},
        success: function() {
            obj.hasClass("icon-star") ? obj.removeClass("icon-star").addClass("icon-star-empty") : obj.removeClass("icon-star-empty").addClass("icon-star");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. +1 for it :) now it send AJAX request and makes changes in server-side but it doesn't change class name :( "icon-star-empty" doesn't change to "icon-star" :( how can I solve this ?

Comment: updated.. if doesn't work - check your Ajax success for being called, because the ternary operator works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/PGdrB/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the href attribute and just prevent the default action from the jquery event.

html

```
<a href="page1" class="icon-star-empty"></a>
<a href="page2" class="icon-star"></a>
<a href="page3" class="icon-star-empty"></a>
```

javascript

```
    $(function(){
        $(document).on('click','a',function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent default click action
            var $this = $(this);  // keeps "this" accessable
            var ajaxURL = $this.attr('href'); // get the url from the "a" tag
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: {id : linkID},
                success: function() {
                    if($this.hasClass("icon-star"))
                        $this.removeClass("icon-star").addClass("icon-star-empty");
                    else
                        $this.removeClass("icon-star-empty").addClass("icon-star");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first, `class` is a reserved name in javascript.

Secondly, if you're doing it with a `jQuery.click` function, then you can just do `$(this).attr('id')` to get the id.

Also, for the success part, you seem to be confused about javascript's function syntax. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I know that is not correct syntax. I wrote it just to explain what I exactly want. Couldt you help me please

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var _ajaxURL,
    _self = $(this);
    if($(this).hasClass('icon-star-empty')){
        _ajaxUrl = "/insertBookmark";
    }else{
        _ajaxUrl = "/deleteBookmark";
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: _ajaxUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id : $(this).prop('id')},
        success: {
           //I have no idea what you want to do right here.
        }
    });
});
```